# Combined List comprehension in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am wondering how to create a new list with the following requirements:

- contain values that are 10 times greater than the numbers from baseList
- contain items that are multiples of  5 and greater than 50

Here is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    baseList = list(range(1, 101))

    list1 = [(i*5) for i in baseList if i % 5 == 0 and i > 50]
        print(list1)

main()
```

This results in the output:

[275, 300, 325, 350, 375, 400, 425, 450, 475, 500]

I am trying to get the following output:

[550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000]

What do I need to change in order to obtain the desired output? I am trying to only use one line of code in order to obtain the new list. This is in Python 3.7. Let me know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you mean `i * 10` instead of `i * 5`?

Comment: `list1 = [(i*10) for i in baseList if not i % 5 and i > 50]`

Comment: Side-note: There is no need to make a `baseList`. Just delete the definition of `baseList` and replace the use of `baseList` in the listcomp with `range(1, 100)` (you needn't listify the `range`; it's already a sequence). Even if you must make it, it needn't be a `list`; your code would produce the same results if you removed the call to `list()` around the `range`, and it would run faster, with less memory to boot.

Comment: This is just a fancy way of saying `print(list(range(550, 1050, 50)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want 10 times greater, but you only multiply `i` by 5 in the list comprehension. Fixed code:

```
baseList = list(range(1, 101))

list1 = [i * 10 for i in baseList if i % 5 == 0 and i > 50]
print(list1)
```

Output:

```
[550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000]
```

Comment: Yep, that was what I was missing. Thanks!